# SwiftUI Binding with CoreData in form

Tags: forms, swiftui, core-data, binding

I have a Core Data model with multiple properties and a form to edit all of this properties.
I want the changes to be "auto-saved". So as soon as I change something in the form, it is saved to my core data context.

I find myself doing a lot of custom bindings to save the my context on change, for example:

```swift
TextField("My string", 
  text: Binding(
    get: {
        model.myString
    }, 
    set: { newValue in
        model.myString = newValue
        try? context.save()
    }
  )
)
```

I'd like to simplify my code and have a special binding bound to core data context to avoid this boilerplate. How could I simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
@ObservedObject var model: SomeType
```

At the top of the View

You can use

```
 .task(id: model.hasChanges) {
      guard model.hasChanges else {return}
      try? context.save()
  }
```

It will save anytime there is a change.

You can put this in a `ViewModifier` for easy access anywhere where you want to auto save.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
struct SimpleItemListView: View {
    @FetchRequest( sortDescriptors: []) var items: FetchedResults<SimpleItem>
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            Text(item.name ?? "")
                .autoSave(item) // Use like this.
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SimpleItemListView()
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
}

//MARK: AutoSave ViewModifier just copy & paste.

extension View {
    func autoSave<MO>(_ object: MO) -> some View where MO: NSManagedObject  {
        modifier(AutoSave(object: object))
    }
}
struct AutoSave<MO>: ViewModifier where MO: NSManagedObject {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @ObservedObject var object: MO
    @State private var alert: (isPresented: Bool, error: LocalError?) = (false, nil)
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .alert(isPresented: $alert.isPresented, error: alert.error, actions: {
                Button("Ok") {
                    alert = (false, nil)
                }
            })
            .task(id: object.hasChanges) {
                guard object.hasChanges else {return}
                do {
                    try await managedObjectContext.perform {
                        try managedObjectContext.save()
                    }
                } catch {
                    alert = (true, LocalError.error(error))
                }
            }
    }
    private enum LocalError: LocalizedError {
        case error(Error)
        
        var errorDescription: String?{
            switch self {
            case .error(let error):
                return error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn’t know we could do that. It’s so smart. Thank you!